# visual basic data bound combo box issues

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a combobox that is a databound item. I would like it to show Please Select as you load the form

I've tryed:

'''ComboBox.SelectedItem = "Please Select:"
and
ComboBox.Text = "Please Select:"
'''

"Please Select" does not want to show at all

this is what ive got (work in progress)

```
ComboBox.SelectedItem = "Please Select:"

ive even tryed 
Share_TypeComboBox.Text = "Please Select:"

'this part works fine
ComboBox.Items.Add("Please Select:")
ComboBox.Items.Add("Choice 1")
ComboBox.Items.Add("Choice 2")
ComboBox.Items.Add("Other")
End Sub

'this is work in progress and may change to selected value instead
Private Sub ComboBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox.TextChanged
If ComboBox.Text = "Other" Then Textbox.show
End Sub
```

ok i know doing on text chaged is bad choice i can attempt on the value changed once i get it working
is it beacuse its a data bound combo box and that why it wont show the required Please Select ?

Comment: _ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0_ should do the work. However this is not a databound combo. You are just settings manually the items collection. In a databound combo you set the DataSource property

Comment: Also SelectedItem should work but, of course, you need to set this property AFTER setting the content of the Items collection

Comment: it adds data in to a data base - i dragged out from the data source tab as a combo box then i added the above to populate

Comment: even if you added the data binding after doing the above the please select will not show

Comment: This is not clear. You "add" data into a database?  Here you "add" items to the combobox. Adding data to the database doesn't seem to have any relevance here. And when you use a DataSource then you don't work with the Items collection.

Comment: the combo box is a dataset item so it would add the selection in to the DB

Comment: ok more questions : as above ive got 2 boxes both data bound so they send the selection to a DB, one Is getting the selections via a bit of programming the other gets it though data bound items - Both dont want to rember the selection and load in with the top values selected yet if you change the record and swap back they both magically rember the selections. i have tryed to build a refresh buttons and test that Nothing happens

Comment: After the rebuild the First rembers the selection the second (data bound) does not any clues what might be going wrong ?

Comment: @Steve ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0 does work for the data bound boxes but you have to watch where you put it. i had to put it in AFTER the data adapter fill request for it to work correct.